# How to fix this error in sending emails by Outh2 using MailCore?

Tags: ios, gmail-api, smtpclient, mailcore2, smtp-auth

Im using mailcore to for sending mails using access token. This work fine in case of using password but by using access tokens its not working. I have changed every combination of ports and connection types but still getting the same issue. I need some help.

```
 MCOSMTPSession * smtpSession = [[MCOSMTPSession alloc] init];
 smtpSession.hostname = @"smtp.gmail.com";
 smtpSession.port = 465;
 smtpSession.username = user; //saved value
 smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeTLS;
 smtpSession.OAuth2Token = token; //saved value(Validated)
 smtpSession.authType = MCOAuthTypeXOAuth2;
 smtpSession.checkCertificateEnabled=NO;

 MCOMessageBuilder * builder = [[MCOMessageBuilder alloc] init];
 MCOAddress *fromAdress=[[MCOAddress alloc]init];
 fromAdress = [MCOAddress addressWithMailbox:user];
 MCOAddress *toAdress=[[MCOAddress alloc]init];
 toAdress = [MCOAddress addressWithMailbox:self.to.text];
 [[builder header] setFrom:fromAdress];
 [[builder header] setTo:@[toAdress]];
 NSString *htmlbody1=@"Body";
 [[builder header] setSubject:@"Some_subject"];
 [builder setHTMLBody:htmlbody1];
 [smtpSession setConnectionLogger:^(void * connectionID,        MCOConnectionLogType type, NSData * data) {
 NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"Response %@",response);
    }];
  NSData * rfc822Data = [builder data];

 MCOSMTPSendOperation *sendOperation = [smtpSession    sendOperationWithData:rfc822Data];
  [sendOperation start:^(NSError *error) {
if(error) {

    NSLog(@"Error sending email: %@", error);
} else {

}
  }];
```

im getting this response
Response 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 gg7sm1578291wjd.10
and getting this error
Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=5 "Unable to authenticate with the current session's credentials.

Comment: You need to generate the oauth2 token properly.

Comment: Does that mean we have to use the GTMOAuth2Authentication class to get the latest access token before we open a session - or does mailcore do that for us?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I don't totally get OAuth. Using GoogleSign in which I believe is giving me the correct Token but still not able to send an email.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that if you want to send emails via Gmail, then you need to either:

1. Use Oauth (more details, see below)
2. For users with 2-step verification enabled, have them set up an [App password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) that they then enter in the app
3. Have users enable the [Less Secure Apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) option on their account

**Using OAuth**

For OAuth, you can use a library like [GTMAppAuth](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth), which allows you to create an OAuth token to use within your app. However, when doing so, you must make sure to set the `scope` correctly when requesting access. Here's some code taken from [the wiki](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth#authorizing):

```objectivec
OIDAuthorizationRequest *request =
    [[OIDAuthorizationRequest alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration
                                                  clientId:kClientID
                                              clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                    scopes:@[OIDScopeOpenID, OIDScopeProfile]
                                               redirectURL:redirectURI
                                              responseType:OIDResponseTypeCode
                                      additionalParameters:nil];
```

**Sending via SMTP**

If you want to use SMTP to send email, then you *must* add `@"https://mail.google.com/" to the` scopes` argument.

Note that it seems that in 2022, Google really doesn't want you directly accessing SMTP. If you use the scope `@"https://mail.google.com/"` in your app, then your app is considered [Restricted](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#restricted-scopes) and it'll need to go through a verification process.

**Sending via Google APIs**

The alternative is to send via the Google APIs. If you want to do this, then you need the `@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"` scope. This will allow you to send email e.g. using the `GTLR` library.

Notes:

If you try to use the `@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"` scope then login via SMTP, you'll get the error `Username and Password not accepted`. You can't use that scope for SMTP, only for the googleapis.

P.S. Why Google can't better document this, is beyond me. I've just volunteered 20 hours of my time to Google for figuring this out.